# Openmp-for loop parallelization

Tags: c, openmp

I have a algorithm in which I have made groups of structures(ie. array of structures). I want that each group should work in a single thread. I am giving the code as follows. the for loop following `#pragma omp for`, i want `i=0` should be executed in one thread, `i=1` in another and so on. Kindly help and suggest me if I am doing correct.

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(min,sgb,div,i) private(th_id)
omp_set_num_threads(4);
{
    th_id=omp_get_thread_num();
    printf("Thread %d\n",th_id);
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    #pragma omp for schedule(static,CHUNKSIZE)
    for(i=0;i<div;i++)
    {           
        sgb[i]=pso(sgb[i],kmax,c1,c2);
        min[i]=sgb[i].gbest;
        printf("in distribute gbest=%f x=%f y=%f index=%d\n",sgb[i].gbest,sgb[i].bestp[0],sgb[i].bestp[1],sgb[i].index);
    }

    #pragma omp barrier
    //fclose(fp);
    m=min[0];
    for(j=0;j<div;j++)
    {
        printf("after barrier   gbest=%f x=%f y=%f\n",sgb[j].gbest,sgb[j].bestp[0],sgb[j].bestp[1]);

        if(m>min[j])
        {
            m=min[j];
            k=j;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does OpenMP [documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) tell you?

Comment: Don't you think that using `pthreads` in your case would be simpler?

Comment: @Eddy_Em: but i dont know how to program in pthreads.

Comment: @meaning-matters: i know what the openmp documentation says abt pragma omp for. but will u please help me in getting out of the doubt/problem

Comment: Read for example `man pthread_create`: it includes a simple example code!

Comment: If you set `CHUNKSIZE` to `1`, then `i=0` will get executed by thread 0, `i=1` by thread 1, `i=2` by thread 2, `i=3` by thread 3, then it will loop in round-robin fashion, i.e. `i=4` will get executed by thread 0, `i=5` by thread 1, and so on.

Comment: @HristoIliev: thanks for the concept. another doubt if u can clear: i have some 128 CPUs(cores) in one node. so how can i distribute the iteration i=0 to 1 core, i=1 to 2nd core and so on. because i am doing heavy amount of iteration i want that each single cpus should be given the task. can u help me in this?

Comment: 1) Enable threads binding (see your compiler's manual); 2) Ensure that there are multiple of 128 iterations in the parallel loop. 3) If each iteration could take varying amount of time, think about switching to loop to dynamic scheduling or using OpenMP tasks if your compiler supports OpenMP 3.0 or later.

Comment: @HristoIliev: the "sgb" is a structure array which has certain number of variables inside it. if suppose div=10 then i want 10 threads to operate in a way, thread0 executes for sgb[0], thread1 executes for sgb[1] and so on. now i want that sgb[0] should be executed by one CPU , sgb[1] by another and so on. so is it possible to do in OpenMP(if yes, which version of OpenMP can solve this issue)?

Comment: (1) + (2) will give you what you want. Watch out for things like false sharing though - it can ruin the performance especially on big NUMA systems like yours.